# Visibility of SQL SERVER spatial data in QGIS depends on srid

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I loaded spatial data in ms sqlserver. Most data are in WGS 84 coordinates, but some are in Pulkovo 42. WGS 84 objects are visible well in QGIS. I checked it in 2.4 and 2.16 versions. But Pulkovo 42 features are invisible. It depends only on value of [geometry_columns].[srid] field. When I change value from 4284 to 4326, features became visible. Records in [spatial_ref_sys] don't affect the result.

Comment: did you set the layer SRS correctly in QGIS?

Comment: Yes, when I set it to 4326 (WGS84) in QGIS and SQLSERVER geometry_columns table, feature is visible. Changing it to another value in both places makes feature invisible in QGIS.

Comment: if the data is in EPSG:4284 then you should set it in SQLServer and let QGIS reproject it to 4326 if that is what the project is in

Comment: Sure, when I set coordinates to 4284 in SQLServer and in QGIS both, features became hidden. Coordinate system of QGIS project don't affect

Comment: are you sure your data is actually in 4286? does it show up when added on it's own with no other data

Comment: Data in 4284 an 4326 are almost the same. Yes, I added only one layer to project

Comment: can you share the data?

Comment: Ok, tomorrow. Out of office.

Comment: It's realy QGIS bug. Tried to add data of different geographical coordinate systems, except WGS-84. Occasionally, data were visualized after some manipulations like "Choose Layer CRS for Project" or "Zoom to Layer" or "Refresh". But then escaped again. It's about QGIS 2.16. QGIS 2.4 never show me non-WGS data. However, the same data from shape-files or Esri file database are OK.

Comment: This problem exists at least 2 years with MySQL geospatial data. I added comment to 'Bug report #13836' on https://issues.qgis.org/